# How to find out which tomcat webapp has a thread leak?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, jconsole

In a production system, which is running 3 Tomcat webapps, we recently noticed that Tomcat crashed because of thread leaking. Two of the three webaps are interplaying with each other, and I would like to find out which one of the 2 components is causing this thread build-up.

**Question:** What is a good way/tool to find out which of the 3 webapps has thread leakage?

My java skills are very rusty. I am not very familiar with Tomcat, and discovering as I go along.
I launched `jconsole` to find out about the thread leak. I am reluctant to install additional (or non-default) tools to troubleshoot this, as this is a production system.

In the jconsole screenshot below, you can see the thread count grows; the Tomcat/catalina process halted at 08:52, a couple of minutes after the thread count maxed out at 893 threads.

[image: jconsole]

Per request,

- the `Connector` element:  `<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads = "600" minSpareThreads = "150" acceptCount = "150" connectionTimeout = "30000" />`
- by "Tomcat crashed", I mean that no more events are logged into the `catalina.log` file, as well as in none of the log files of the 3 webapps. Only the underlying apache is logging events, with HTTP 500 errors.

Comment: Is this a single Tomcat instance? What do you mean Tomcat "crashed"?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the active `<Connector>` elements from your Tomcat's `conf/server.xml` file. **Please remember to sanitize any secret information, such as passwords.**

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: done. Not sure if the `connector` info i inserted is what you are looking for, though

Comment: So is the Tomcat process running anymore at all? It's quite unusual for Tomcat to become completely inert. If the process is running, take a thread dump and see what all the threads are doing. You have a thread-limit of 600 on that connector, so something else must be creating those extra threads. Is there anything in the log files which might explain what's going on?

Comment: jstack gives no clues of hints (it should show a lotta threads that are idle after awhile...)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have the luxury of deploying new code on the system.

The simplest change that helped me in a similar situation - also using tomcat - was to give each executor/threadpool/thread a meaningful name, one that could be traced back to the webapp *and* the module that created the thread.

Voila, thread dumps were suddenly looking friendly. This was done in a pinch too, via guava/[ThreadFactoryBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

Run each of the web applications in a different Tomcat instance. You probably have some nginx/Apache instance, load balancer or something like that, in front of the Tomcat, which you could reconfigure to point to separate individual Tomcats for each web application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it's a production system, so to be honest, I want to avoid such big changes. I was hoping there is a less involved approach...

Comment: The other option is to do this, but only in a separate performance testing environment, and simulate users hitting the system using Selenium or JMeter or Gatling or some tool like that.